# What are the minimum permissions needed to run a Scheduled Task on Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions, scheduled-task

I'm trying to set up a scheduled task on my server 2003 box (that is sitting on the WWW) to read web logs into a database.

When I run the .cmd file that I have set up using `runas`, the task succeeds.  However, when I try to schedule the task under the user, I get the following error:

```
"ImportToday.job" (ImportToday.cmd) 9/15/2010 2:37:30 PM ** ERROR **
    Unable to start task.
    The specific error is:
    0x80070005: Access is denied.
    Try using the Task page Browse button to locate the application.
```

Adding the account `logimporter` into the `Administrators` group lets the scheduled task succeed, but this is really not a long-term option.

I have tried adding the `Log on as a service` right, and the account currently has the `Log on as a batch job` right.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And..... I found it.

By default, `CMD.EXE` requires special permissions when not logged on to a desktop session.

So, by adding `Read` and `Read & Execute` permissions for the account has fixed my problem.

That is:

```
cacls C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /e /g logimporter:r
```

fixed it for me.